# How to sort array in Reducer ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

In the state.unsortedAllHighScores there will be an array output, but when I try to get that state and sort that in state.sortedAllHighScores, it stays empty? My expected result would be an array that should be sorted after every dispatch, so when the dispatched is being called, it should output the sorted array. This is a highscore ranking, so you know why I want to have that sort function in here.

```js
const initialState = {
    sortedAllHighScores: [],
    unsortedAllHighScores: []
};

export const game = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {

case types.HIGH_SCORE: {
            return {
                ...state,
                unsortedAllHighScores: [...state.unsortedAllHighScores, state.updatedCurrentScore],
                sortedAllHighScores: [].concat(state.unsortedAllHighScores).sort((a, b) => {
                    console.log(b - a);
                    return b - a;
                })
            }
        }
     }
```

Comment: what happens if you just sort it like this `[...state.unsortedAllHighScores.sort()]`

Comment: 1. You're trying to use the result of an assignment to uAHS , inside the assignment to sAHS array. 
2. You should add `state.updateCurrentScore` to your initial state to avoid confusion on how that's being set.
3. I'd break up the assignment to `unsortedAllHighScores` from the `HIGH_SCORE` action type, maybe something like `SET_SCORES`, because you have to update the state of `unsortedAllHighScores` before you can then use it in the `sortedAllHighScores` state as a sorted value. In short, you're doing way too many things at once and it's yielding confusing bugs. Atomization is your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you ever try like this:

```
case types.HIGH_SCORE: {
    const tmp = [...state.unsortedAllHighScores, state.updatedCurrentScore]
    return {
        ...state,
        unsortedAllHighScores: tmp,
        sortedAllHighScores: [].concat(tmp).sort((a, b) => {
             console.log(b - a);
             return b - a;
        })
    }
}
```